Proving commutativity of matrices with a given property
Prove that for any two matrices $ A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) $ with the property $ BA = A^2 + B $, the matrices commute, i.e., $ AB = BA $.
The property rewrites as $ B(A - I_n) = A^2 $ and we can take two cases: when $ A - I_n $ is invertible and when it is not. The first case is easy to prove but I can’t find correct way to prove the second one.

$A-I$ is always invertible since $B(A-I) = (A+I)(A-I) + I$ implies $(B-A-I)(A-I) = I$.
